# local wireless is slow

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, airport-extreme

I'm trying to transfer data from one mbp to another over my local wireless, and the most I get is around 5 - 10 MB/s.  Is this normal?

[image]

Comment: Which frequency range are you using? What's your router? Have you done a site survey?

Comment: I think 2.4ghz, a/b/n.  Router is an Airport Extreme.  Site survey - not sure how to?

Comment: There have been 7+ models of AirPort Extreme since the first 802.11g AirPort Extreme in 2003. Knowing exactly which model is important. It's also important to know if you're using 2.4GHz or 5GHz. You can use wider channels and get higher throughput in 5GHz. "2.4GHz a/b/n" makes no sense, because 802.11a doesn't work in 2.4GHz; it's 5GHz-only.

Answer (score 0):

Disk and file I/O rates are usually given in MebiBytes per second (1,048,576's of 8-bit bytes per second). Network speeds are usually given in megabits per second (1,000,000's of individual bits per second).  So your reported 5-10 MebiBytes/sec translates into 41-82 megabits/sec.

On wireless-to-wireless transfers on the same AP, every packet must be transmitted across the channel twice (once from the source to the AP, then again from the AP to the destination). This cuts your effective bandwidth in half. So each leg of your Wi-Fi link appears to be capable of 82 - 164 megabits/sec.

TCP throughput over 802.11n is often around 70% of the PHY (physical layer signaling) rate, so your PHY rate may be around 117 - 234 megabits/sec.

Since Apple products limit themselves to 20MHz-wide channels in 2.4GHz (to leave room for Bluetooth), the max PHY rate of a 2 spatial stream device (Macs before 2011, Apple APs before late 2009) is 144.4Mbps, and the max PHY rate of a 3 spatial stream device is 216.6. So the low end of your throughput range is pretty good, and the high end of your throughput range exceeds what's possible in 2.4GHz.

The 5GHz frequency band allows 40MHz-wide channels, which slightly more than doubles the throughput. The max 2-stream PHY rate is 300 megabits/sec, and the max 3-stream PHY rate is 450 megabits/sec. So you're not maxing out what 5GHz can do, although I'd consider the speed you're getting to be decent if the machines aren't both in the same room as the AP.

To improve your throughput without buying new equipment, wire one machine via Ethernet to a LAN port on the AirPort base station, and make sure the other one is using 5GHz and at least 2m, but less than 6m, from the base station.